# Higher KW on the secondary winding of a transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer

I have a step down 3 phase Delta/Wye transformer. 400 volts on the primary and 208 volts on the secondary. I have about 4 amps per phase on the primary and 13 amps on the secondary.

How is this possible? It should be around 8 amps on the secondary but the amperage has more than tripled. This means that the transformer is generating over 1 KW of power by itself.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the transformer's rating plate or nameplate?

Comment: Did you measure the actual voltage too?

Comment: No, but it is a 50 KVA Delta/Wye K-13 xfmr.

Comment: That is the actual voltage.

Comment: 398 phase to phase input. 206 phase to phase output. Neutral ground bond is connected.

Comment: Post a schematic as to how exactly it is hooked up.  I will guarantee you though that the transformer is not generating any extra power.

Comment: Not sure how to post an image. 3 wire (ABC) with ground primary feeding the delta side of the transformer. 4 wire (ABCN) with ground coming off the Wye secondary side. The XO is bonded with the grounding conductor. It feeds a panel that is all single phase loads.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 3-phase input complicates things so the calculation is not the same as for a "normal" (1 phase) transformer.

There's a calculator and some formulas [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/electric/kVA_to_Amp_Calculator.htm)

If I fill in:

Three phase
P = 4.8 kVA

Line to line voltage = 208 V

then I get the 13.3 A

BUT if I select:

Line to neutral voltage = 208 V

I get 7.7 A

So it depends on how you connect the loads to the transformer, see [Three-phase power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power).

Also [this](http://ecmweb.com/nec/understanding-basics-delta-transformer-calculations) might also help you understand.